# Using Behat Predefined steps, i want to select value from this dropdown

Tags: testing, drupal, automation, behat, mink

[image]I am trying to select third option from this dropdown (shown in image below).
I want to do it using Behat/mink predefined steps.
Any suggestions?
[image]

Comment: please avoid posting code as image, use code snippet instead

Comment: You need to click some elements the one that shows the list and after the element from the list, this is not a regular `select` element.

Comment: @lauda Thankyou for the quick reply. I understand what you are saying. Then I should see an "ul.dropbutton" element
And the "ul.dropbutton" element should contain "Add Content: Slider" These tests are passing. but i am not able to click  "Add Content: Slider". It fails

Comment: use a css selector like this `input[value='Add Content: Slider']` Please edit and update the question with the code you tried and the error you are getting